# Which is the best design for categorizing items?

Tags: vba, ms-access, database-design, user-interface, relationship

I have four levels for categorizing items according to their attributes. Some items may not require all subcategory levels and some items may share the same subcategory values.

Examples:

```
Category1   Category2   Category3   Category4
---------   ---------   ---------   ---------
Jewelry     Ring        Wedding
Jewelry     Bracelet    Serpentine 
Jewelry     Necklace    Serpentine
Equipment   Tool        Power       Drill                
Equipment   Tool        Hand        Jigsaw
Accessory   Battery     AA
Accessory   Movie       DVD         Action
Accessory   Game        PS3         Combat
```

I want the lookup tables to contain values which are related to each item so that when users select a value from the dropdown list in the first category, the corresponding values in the next subcategory will automatically drop down (cascade), and so on.

I will predefine non-deletable, non-updatable values for most common items, however I cannot provide all possible items, for which I want to allow users to add values from the second level on down.

The objective for classifying each item is to provide a uniform method for describing items and for queries to effectively return all desired items.

Questions:

1. How can I make sure that new values which are added by users will link properly to parent or child values?
2. Should I allow users to add new categories and subcategories or should I force them to only select from pre-defined values, chose 'Other' value if their item does not fit into one of the pre-defined and enter a free-form comment?
3. Is the current method I have defined the best way or do you have a better suggestion?

Below are the current tables and relationships I have defined:

[image]

```
Columns        MS-Access     Informix   Comments
-------------- ------------  --------   ----------------------------------------
Primary keys   Autonumber    SERIAL  
Foreign keys   Long Integer  INTEGER 
English        Text          VARCHAR    Description in English language.
Spanish        Text          VARCHAR    Description in Spanish language.
NonDelete      Yes/No        CHAR(1)    Cant delete predefined value if TRUE.
NonUpdate      Yes/No        CHAR(1)    Cant update predefined value if TRUE.
Deleted        Yes/No        CHAR(1)    User-defined value cant be used anymore. 
StockKeptUnit  Yes/No        CHAR(1)    Non-serialized inventory item if TRUE.
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't they properly link by definition? That is sort of the point of the PK/FK relationship, after all.

Presumably creation of a new tlkpItemCat2 involves selecting a valid parent tlkpItemCat1, or the INSERT would fail. As long as tlkpItemCat2.ItemCat1_SIID is defined as NOT NULL, you're pretty much assured of a valid relationship.

That doesn't guarantee that the end-user hasn't declared that a Necktie is a Power Tool, but that's a whole different problem.

---

Now, from experience with this exact issue (object categorisation), I can tell you that although this design looks quite elegant and useful, it is awful from a usability perspective. Your user has to know the hierarchy *in advance* to quickly locate the correct category for an item. And once end-users start adding levels to your hierarchy, it becomes a nightmare of back-and-forth, dead-end searches trying to locate the correct combination of Cat1/Cat2/Cat3 to apply - which leads to anything-will-do-just-to-get-past-this-screen categorisation.

A better approach is to allow the user to simply type in 'Jigsaw', and return a list along the lines:

```
Did you mean:
 []   Equipment | Tool       | Power  | Jigsaw
 []   Equipment | Tool       | Hand   | Jigsaw
 []   Game      | Childrens  | Jigsaw
 []   Accessory | DVD-Movie  | Horror | Jigsaw
 []   ... or [something else]?
```

Yes, it's more work, but from a UI and UX perspective, worthwhile.

Comment: Example: A customer sold a Necklace with Serpentine links to user. The user knows this is a Jewelry item so user selects that value in Category1. Then a Cat2 dropdown list appears with all types of Jewelry and user selects Necklace. Then Cat3 list appears with types of Necklaces and user selects Serpentine. I would think that this kind of UI would be easier for users? What I want to know is if a Necklace and a Bracelet can both be Serpentine style, do I have to repeat the value 'Serpentine' in Category3 with the related foreign key from Category2 and what happens when users add new values?

Comment: Perhaps I should only provide a finite number of values for each category, include the value 'Other' at each level and not allow users to add new values? My objective is to standardize the way users categorize the most commonly used items so that when users query the table they can locate items which match the desried values.

Comment: Yes, you will have two "Serpentine" records, one a child of Necklace and one a child of Bracelet. As I said, there is nothing intrinsically wrong with the design from a technical standpoint, but usability is another issue entirely. I cannot emphasise enough how much more effective a 'bottom-up' search approach will be. From experience, I can tell you that how you categorise objects and how your users do will not be the same. Is a lamp an electrical appliance or a piece of furniture? Your opinion and your user's may differ. Guide them. Show them all the matching categories and let them pick.

Comment: For that matter the assumption that every user would automatically record a necklace or bracelet by the type of links it has seems optimistic. I once worked on a Police database where Lost/Stolen/Found/Recovered property was recorded. *Exactly* the same issue as you and your pawnbroking system. Throwing away the hierarchical selection approach and replacing with what I suggested in my answer earlier was both a usability and data quality *revelation*.

Comment: A problem, which I can anticipate, with letting users type in the values is that most users dont spell correctly or type in a synonym of an existing value, thus I feel compelled to pre-define and pre-construct the hierarchies of the most common items they've encountered, based on the existing data of their current application which provides only one long text field for entering the item descriptions in a free-form manner.

Answer (score 1):

This should allow for infinite categories. You'll need to enforce non-orphaning through your UI or OnChange events.

[image]

Then your table content would look like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unlimited categories would be more flexible, however your design appears to be denormalized since I would have to repeat many of the the same values for each particular item. I'm also inclined to limit the categories to only four levels since unlimited levels could turn into a tangled up nightmare.

Comment: How do you mean that you'd need to repeat? This offers less repetition as far as I can tell? example? I hear what you're saying about the tangles mess, there are ways to control that through the UI though or through access's new triggers features.

Comment: Forgive my inexperience, I misunderstood your first example, as each row provides a referenece to the ParentCategoryID. So will I be able to display only the values in a subcategory dropdown list which correspond to a ParentCategoryID?

Comment: You can write a recursive query to walk up to the parentest parent. Probably will need to be done with VBA because Access's SQL doesn't like recursion. Once you have that you can have every Item and it's full position in the category hierarchy